# Change SVG bounding box position

Tags: svg, shapes

i have a svg circle and a svg rectangle, i want to put rectangle inside circle such that rectangle position be in center of circle.
i know about 'getBBox()' method to get size and position of bounding box, but i cant set the size and position.
and my problem is it seems the center of rectangle is top-left corner of it.
here's the example code :

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
<circle id="aaa" r="100" fill="red" transform="translate(150,150)"></circle>
<rect id="circle2" width="50" height="50" fill="green" transform="translate(150,150)">   </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: You would use setAttribute on the rect's x,y,width and height attributes. You've not shown any javascript, what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is i have many shapes including star,paths,..
and i want to align one shape into another , and i don't know x,y of center of each shape

Comment: That's not what you said in the question though is it?

Comment: You don't say whether you are working with an existing SVG, or creating the shapes at runtime.  Finding a solution for the former is very tricky.  Finding a solution for the latter is easy.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cx` and `cy` of the circle will be `null` if not set explicitly, in fact they are both equally `0`. From the center point of the circle, you can derive the `top-left` point (position) of the rectangle using the following formula:

```
x = cx - width / 2;
y = cy - height / 2;
```

So you can try the following script to set the rectangle at the center of the circle:

```
var rect = document.getElementById('circle2');
var circ = document.getElementById("aaa");
var cx = circ.getAttribute("cx");
var cy = circ.getAttribute("cy");
if(cx == null) cx = 0;
if(cy == null) cy = 0;
var w = parseInt(rect.getAttribute("width"));
var h = parseInt(rect.getAttribute("height"));
rect.setAttribute("x", cx - w/2);
rect.setAttribute("y", cy - h/2);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0goz3f8o/).

Answer (score 0):

In your example SVG, you are creating the circle centred on the origin and then moving it to 150,150.  It looks like you are attempting to do the same for the square, except you haven't centred it on the origin properly.

If you position the square correctly, it will work.  The square needs to extend from -25,-25 to 25,25.  See below:

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <circle r="100" fill="red" transform="translate(150,150)"></circle>
  <rect x="-25" y="-25" width="50" height="50" fill="green" transform="translate(150,150)">   </rect>
</svg>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ecdkpntz/)

Answer (score 0):

My advice: Usually easier to create around origin, `<g>`roup both and `translate`. Rotation is also simplified since it is just rotation around origin.

1. Create circle around origin (ie: `cx=0` and `cy=0`)
2. Create `<rect>` around origin `(x,y), (-x,y), (-x,-y), (x,-y)`
3. Add `<g>` tag around `<circle>` and `<rect>` and `translate` this group.